Count occurrences of each type of event within a time window in Pandas
I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

event_timestamp: Timestamp of each event.
event_type: Type of the event.

I need to add a column for each unique event_type to count how
many events of that event_type occurred within a 10ms window before
each row's event_timestamp.
data = {
    'event_timestamp': [
        '2024-02-01 08:02:09.065315961', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.125612099', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.160326512',
        '2024-02-01 08:02:09.540206541', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.571751697', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.571784060',
        '2024-02-01 08:02:09.574368029', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.574390737', '2024-02-01 08:02:09.578245099',
        '2024-02-01 08:02:10.077399943', '2024-02-01 08:02:10.077424252', '2024-02-01 08:02:10.081648527'
    ],
    'event_type': [
        'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])

For the above input, I want an output like this:
             event_timestamp         event_type  count_A  count_B  count_C
0  2024-02-01 08:02:09.065315961          A        0        0        0
1  2024-02-01 08:02:09.125612099          B        0        0        0
2  2024-02-01 08:02:09.160326512          A        0        0        0
3  2024-02-01 08:02:09.540206541          A        0        0        0
4  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571751697          C        0        0        0
5  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571784060          B        0        0        1
6  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574368029          A        0        1        1
7  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574390737          C        1        1        1
8  2024-02-01 08:02:09.578245099          B        1        1        2
9  2024-02-01 08:02:10.077399943          A        0        0        0
10 2024-02-01 08:02:10.077424252          C        1        0        0
11 2024-02-01 08:02:10.081648527          B        1        1        0


The columns count_A, count_B, and count_C represent the number of occurrences of event_type 'A', 'B', and 'C' that happened within a 10ms window before each row's event_timestamp.

For example, for the row with event_timestamp 2024-02-01 08:02:09.065315961, we see:

count_A is 1 because there was 1 event of type 'A' within the 10ms window before that timestamp.
count_B is 0 and count_C is 0 because there were no events of type 'B' or 'C' in that window.




I don't find the same values for the following row, please double check your output and if you disagree with my output, please break down the computation for a few more rows

For instance, at 2024-02-01 08:02:09.540206541 there was only 1 A event within the last 10ms, not 2.

I solved this a few minutes ago. I attempted to match your output exactly but was unable to until I realised that your example output is incorrect. Please, verify your example outputs and ensure accuracy to avoid confusion in the future.

IIUC, you could produce the columns with get_dummies, then perform a rolling.sum on 10ms to get the counts, finally merge back to the original DataFrame:
out = df.merge(pd
   .get_dummies(df['event_type']).add_prefix('count_')
   .set_axis(df['event_timestamp']).sort_index()
   .rolling('10ms').sum().convert_dtypes(),
               left_on='event_timestamp', right_index=True,
)

Variant:
out = df.merge(df
   .set_index('event_timestamp').sort_index()
   ['event_type'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('count_')
   .rolling('10ms').sum().convert_dtypes(),
               left_on='event_timestamp', right_index=True,
)

Output:
                 event_timestamp event_type  count_A  count_B  count_C
0  2024-02-01 08:02:09.065315961          A        1        0        0
1  2024-02-01 08:02:09.125612099          B        0        1        0
2  2024-02-01 08:02:09.160326512          A        1        0        0
3  2024-02-01 08:02:09.540206541          A        1        0        0
4  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571751697          C        0        0        1
5  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571784060          B        0        1        1
6  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574368029          A        1        1        1
7  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574390737          C        1        1        2
8  2024-02-01 08:02:09.578245099          B        1        2        2
9  2024-02-01 08:02:10.077399943          A        1        0        0
10 2024-02-01 08:02:10.077424252          C        1        0        1
11 2024-02-01 08:02:10.081648527          B        1        1        1

And if you want only the previous:
tmp = (pd.get_dummies(df['event_type']).add_prefix('count_')
         .set_axis(df['event_timestamp']).sort_index()
      )

out = df.merge(tmp.rolling('10ms').sum().sub(tmp).convert_dtypes(),
               left_on='event_timestamp', right_index=True,
)

Output:
                 event_timestamp event_type  count_A  count_B  count_C
0  2024-02-01 08:02:09.065315961          A        0        0        0
1  2024-02-01 08:02:09.125612099          B        0        0        0
2  2024-02-01 08:02:09.160326512          A        0        0        0
3  2024-02-01 08:02:09.540206541          A        0        0        0
4  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571751697          C        0        0        0
5  2024-02-01 08:02:09.571784060          B        0        0        1
6  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574368029          A        0        1        1
7  2024-02-01 08:02:09.574390737          C        1        1        1
8  2024-02-01 08:02:09.578245099          B        1        1        2
9  2024-02-01 08:02:10.077399943          A        0        0        0
10 2024-02-01 08:02:10.077424252          C        1        0        0
11 2024-02-01 08:02:10.081648527          B        1        0        1


Thanks, very efficient and straightfoward... Appologies for incorrect example output

@IGottaLearnMath no worries, but please edit the question to add the correct output for clarity to future readers.
